# Prove this inequality: $\sum{\frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{a^2+2ab}}}\ge\frac{\sqrt{3}}{abc}$

Tags: inequality

Let $a,b,c>0$. Prove this inquality:

$\frac{1}{a^2\sqrt{a^2+2ab}}+\frac{1}{b^2\sqrt{b^2+2bc}}+\frac{1}{c^2\sqrt{c^2+2ac}}\ge\frac{\sqrt{3}}{abc}$

Comment: Where does this come from? Please don't give orders.

Comment: This inequality is my problem by processing .

Comment: "by processing"?

Comment: Oh, sorry. You can understand it as by composing :-ss

Answer (score 1):

hint:

$\sqrt{a^2+2ab}=\sqrt{\dfrac{3a(a+2b)}{3}}\le \dfrac{2a+b}{\sqrt{3}}$

then the inequality becomes: $\sum_{cyc}\dfrac{bc}{a(2a+b)} \ge1$  which is easier .

Answer (score 0):

Another Hint/way:

analytical soln.: The equality will be satisfied when all terms are equal.

Proof: let $0 < K=a < b < c$ then $\sqrt(a^2+bc)$ is least term and by making b=c=K, we get higher sum.